# Loading logger config takes long time during startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog, asp.net-core-3.1

Recently I migrated project to AspNetCore 3.1 from 2.2, and started using Visual Studio 2019. Since then it takes about one minute to start application. Most of this time app is getting nlog.config:

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        LogManager.LoadConfiguration(System.String.Concat
(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/nlog.config")); //here's where it hangs

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            //.AddJsonFile($"rabbitConfig.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

I know that IHostingEnvironment is obsolete, can it cause this problem? What should I change to make it load faster?

Comment: use `Path.Combine` instead of `String.Concat`. it may help!

Comment: I doubt hosting config is your problem, its more your LogManger taking so long to process the config file (i.e. big complex logging rules). By splitting it (making the path into a variable first then pass the variable you'll see that too. Blind claiming its something w/o investigating is pretty lazy way to do it

Comment: Regardless of your issue here, you should move the configuration setup out of your `Startup` and into the `ConfigureAppConfiguration` on the host in the `Program.cs`.

Comment: I don't have complex logging rules, it's copypasted boilerplate(maybe with long path, but that shouldn't be an issue), and I don't think String.Concat is causing this(will try it though). Will check with config setup in program.cs. It worked fine with VS2017 and aspnetcore 2.2. On my colleague's pc it loads fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your co-workers are not having issues, then you are most likely a victim of the ridiculous slow symbol loading in Visual Studio 2019. One work-around is to [Enable Just My Code](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3659#issuecomment-548546560)

You can try and skip the automatic scanning for assemblies to load NLog-extensions:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   Configuration = configuration;

   //disable NLog assembly scanning
   NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.Default = new NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory(typeof(NLog.ILogger).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

   //here's where it hangs
   NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration(System.String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/nlog.config"));

    ...
}
```

It is also recommended to use NLog 4.6.8, as it has several optimizations for speeding up the configuration loading.

Notice that if you have enabled NLog InternalLogger on Trace-Level, then it will also hurt performance.

Remember that if you disable the default MEL-Console-Logger, or filters away Info-Level-messages from `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime`-Logger then the hosting-environment will timeout waiting for the expected startup messages. Make sure to configure NLog-Console-output or keep the AddConsole-output:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Hosting-Lifetime-Startup-Messages

In ASP.NET Core 2 then it would write directly to Console, but with ASP.NET Core 3 then it uses the MEL-ILogger called `Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime` (Remember to configure MEL-Filter and NLog-Filter to not discard these messages in ASP.NET Core 3)

Answer (score 1):

Check your Extensions in the config. Likely the library does not exist, which explicitly causes this problem when loading NLog. 
My guess is NLog is searching around for the DLL, or as Rolf said, attempting to load the pdb (except it doesn't exist).

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Extended" />
</extensions>
```

In my case, `NLog.Extended` needed changed to `NLog.Web.AspNetCore`, since NLog.Extended doesn't exist in .net core. Which comes down to a bad copy paste from another project.

User of NLog should check their nlog.config, and use the correct sample for their target framework, such as:  [AspNetCore 2](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2) or [AspNetCore 3](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-3)